# Windows 8 app bar not working on google maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, windows-8, appbar

I am developing a simple app for windows 8. 
I have used  iframe of Google maps in my application. 
The problem is when I right click(when my mouse pointer is on top of the map) the app bar doesn't shown up because in Google Map by default that state is handled for zooming, sliding etc.
 But in my application I want an additional functionality of app bar. I tried changing few options of "var mapOptions" in Google map "initialize() function" like zoomControl: false etc. but none helped.
Please suggest me how to come up with this problem.
hoping for positive response.

Comment: Do you want the map to respond to other events, just not the right-click event?

Comment: yes, this can really help me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to solve your problem with Google Maps, but Bing Maps will work.  Here's an announcement:

http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2012/10/03/bing-maps-sdks-for-windows-store-apps-now-available.aspx